# Django: how to specify `include_blank=False` in `modelform_factory` using `formfield_callback`?

Tags: django

I am using the `django.forms.modelform_factory()` function. Some of the database fields are `IntegerField`s with `choices`, so Django defaults to using a `django.forms.TypedChoiceField` that has a blank choice ("--------------"). I'm using the `RadioSelect` widget, so it's redundant to have a blank choice. How do I get rid of the blank choice?

*(I'm answering my own question, but of course if you have a better answer, feel free to share!)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`modelform_factory`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/models/#django.forms.models.modelform_factory)  has a  `formfield_callback` kwarg, which "is a callable that takes a model field and returns a form field."

For example:

```
from django.forms import modelform_factory
from yourapp.models import Person
import django  # only importing this for type hints

def formfield_callback(f, **kwargs):
    # type: (django.db.models.fields.Field, dict) -> django.forms.Field

    ## pick the field or fields you want to modify.
    ## This example uses the `name` of the field to decide
    if f.name == 'job':
        ## override the 'choices' attribute
        kwargs['choices'] = f.get_choices(include_blank=False)
        ## if you want to, you can override the 'widget' here also
        kwargs['widget'] = RadioSelect
    ## regardless of whether you changed anything, return the result of 
    ## the normal formfield function so everything still works
    return f.formfield(**kwargs)


modForm = modelform_factory(Person, fields=["job", "age"],
                formfield_callback=formfield_callback)
```